# How do I force nodes to be drawn next to each other with Graphviz dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm looking to have a series of nodes in a row, joined by an edge. This works fine when the graph's `rankdir` is set to `TB` or `BT`, but it rearranges the nodes when I set it to `LR` or `RL` so they're no longer next to each other. Example images are included.

I've taken my code and stripped it down to it's minimum point for demonstration. The code is the same for both of the following graphs, aside from line 2 (which specifies `rankdir`):

```
digraph{
    rankdir=LR;
    node[shape=box,fontcolor=white,color=black,fillcolor=black,style=filled];
    edge[dir=none,color=black];
    
    Josh -> JoshParent;
    JoshParent -> Hero;
    JoshParent[shape=circle,label="",height=0.0001,width=0.0001];
    
    {
        rank=same;
        Kae[label="Kae"];
        Hero[label="Hero"];
        Kae -> Hero;
    }
    
    Kae -> KaeParent;
    Hero -> HeroParent;
    KaeParent -> Liz;
    KaeParent[shape=circle,label="",height=0.0001,width=0.0001];
    HeroParent -> George;
    HeroParent[shape=circle,label="",height=0.0001,width=0.0001];
    
    {
        rank=same;
        George[label="George"];
        Liz[label="Liz"];
        Ocean[label="Ocean"];
        Egg[label="Egg"];
        Liz -> Ocean -> Egg;
    }
}
```

This is what's shown with `rankdir=TB`:

[image]

This is what's shown with `rankdir=LR`:

[image]

As you can see, from the `LR` image, the nodes have been drawn in the order "Ocean, George, Egg", rather than "Ocean, Egg, George" as it is with the `TB` image.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the order by adding an explicit but invisible edge from `Egg` to `George`:

```
Liz -> Ocean -> Egg;                // last line of your code
Egg -> George[ style = invis ];     // additional edge
```

This produces

[image]

I don't have an explanation for the different behaviour between `TB` and `LR`, though.